# PDO and MySQL stored procedure. Not returning out param

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, prepared-statement

When using PDO, I should be able to select the param and echo it. All I get however is NULL. When I use Workbench, I can see it just fine.

Can anyone tell me why this is so?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testing(OUT ret int)
BEGIN SET ret=12; END;

// On workbench returns '12' - Correct       
call testing(@ret);
select @ret;

// PHP/PDO returns NULL
$stmt=Db()->prepare("CALL testing(@ret)");
$stmt->execute();
$param = Db()->query("SELECT @ret")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($param);
```

**EDIT:**
I was just about convinced that this may have been a specific issue with Windows so I uploaded this example to my UNIX server and get exactly the same result, NULL.

Comment: How you check for errors and see what they say http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Pablo, yes, I have checked for errors and there are none being reported by MySQL or PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you miss the call to `bindParam()`. From [the PHP doc examples](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
<?php
/* Call a stored procedure with an INOUT parameter */
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('CALL puree_fruit(?)');
$sth->bindParam(1, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 12);
$sth->execute();
print("After pureeing fruit, the colour is: $colour");
?>
```

**UPDATE**

I missed the MySQL part. MySQL [doesn't support](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35935) binding output parameters via its C API. In the bug report it's said you must use SQL level variables:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(@a)");
$stmt->execute();
print_r($db->query("SELECT @a")->fetchAll());
```

but this is exactly what you do, and it doesn't work. I'm trying this myself right now.

Comment: MySQL doesn't supporting binding output parameters via its C API.  You must use SQL level variables:

Comment: Thanks Raffaele but no dice. I've been there and done that as well but still get NULL returned. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: Raffaele, I know where you got that example, right off of PHPs site. I tried that same exact example and could not get anything to be returned. I'm curious if you'll have any luck. Please let me know.

Comment: Raffaele, I just ran your update example and here is the result: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [@ret] => [0] => ) )`

Comment: @user1709311 On my side it works fine. Can you execute [this script](http://pastebin.com/2aiJdEzw)?

Comment: I just tried your code and I get `Array([0] => Array([@a] => 1357158688 [0] => 1357158688))` which means it works, which means I'm completely in the dark. I've got exceptions enabled in my connection string and don't see anything. Why does your code work? I guess that's for me to find. :)  Thanks my frined!

Comment: Raffaele, I have compared your connection string to mine and it is identical. My issue is that if I call my static database class method `connect` where I am trying to make this query, I don't get the return value. However, if I **move** that connection string into the method where I want to make that query, I get the return value. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Anyone else experiencing strange behavior should add `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` to their PDO connection. In my case, what was happening was that a new instance of PDO was being created thereby returning NULL after the execute statement. When I added this to my PDO connection string, it began to work. A big thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 1):

I see a bug here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11638.

try this

```
   insert "SELECT @someOutParameter" in your stored procedure and then use: 

    <?php 
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL SomeStoredProcedure(?, ?)"); 
    $stmt ->execute(array($someInParameter1, $someInParameter2)); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Hey Rizon. Thanks for the link. I actually just found that myself and was going through it. I'll give your example a try and let you know but you know the really strange thing? I've got other applications that use these procedures and they are all still working. I don't know why this won't work for me; I've not upgraded MySQL or PHP.

Comment: Rizon, this is the output: `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST testing('1')' at line 1'`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, were you able to get any of this to work?

Comment: no just finding something that might work, did you use CALL, i recently edited it.

Comment: Rizon, Raffaele gave me a patebin that works for me. There is something, somewhere probably in my DBAL that is preventing this from working. Everything that he has given me is exactly as he has it. The only exception is the PDO connection string. I've got to have something going on there. My friend, thank you so much for sticking this out with me and for all your help!

Comment: Oh, I will. Thanks. I've been on this since 6:00AM

Comment: Hey Rizon, as it turns out, the second query that would have brought my return value back was being wiped out by a new PDO instance. I just added `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` to my connection string and it's working perfectly. Thanks again, my friend for sticking with me on this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$stmt=Dbh->prepare("CALL testing(@ret)");
$stmt->execute();
$param = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($param);
```

Comment: Rizon, I just ran that and what I get is: `array(0) { }`